# How to override Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute class methods in Magento 2.2?

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I have tried to override **_processAttributeOptions()**  method from **Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute** in my custom module. but the function does not override. Here is my code:

Namespace\Module_Name\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute" type="Namespace\Module_Name\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute" />
</config>
```

Namespace\Module_Name\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module_Name\Model\ResourceModel\Entity;

class Attribute extends \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute
{
 protected function _processAttributeOptions($object, $option)
    {
             //here is my custom code with core
    }
}
```

Please help me to override this method in Magento 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter namespace and module name in lower case then try to replace it with CamelCase like `namespace\module_name` with `Namespace\Module` and rename folders also.

Comment: sry my typing mistake, I have actually give Namespace\Module

Comment: This  _processAttributeOptions() method is not calling from my file

Comment: Please answer to me.